# Rails 4 respond_with include association with WHERE

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, responders

I'm using rails `respond_with` to send a JSON response to the client, and I'm trying to figure out how to use the `includes` option in `respond_with` along with a `where` clause in my association

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ratings
   has_many :movies, through: :ratings
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :movie
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ratings
   has_many :users, through: :ratings
end
```

In my controller action, I have:

```
def create
   movies = Movie.order("RANDOM()").limit(3)
   respond_with(movies, include: :ratings)
   // I'd like to do something like 
   // respond_with(movies, include: :ratings WHERE user: current_user)

end
```

However, this is responding with ALL the ratings for those three movies. I want to restrict it the ratings of just that particular user

Comment: You could add a where statement on the movies variable - something like `movies = Movie.where(user_id: @user.id).order...`

Comment: @abbott567, that won't work. There is no `user_id` column on the `Movie` model in the asker's schema. That query will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
def create
  movies = Movie.order("RANDOM()").limit(3)
  # EDIT
  # movies = movies.merge(current_user.movies).includes(:ratings)
  movies = movies.joins(:ratings).merge(current_user.ratings).includes(:ratings)
  respond_with(movies)
end
```

Although that doesn't make much sense in a `create` action.

**NOTE**

The `movies` query above will generate the following SQL (2 commands; note that some of your fields will differ since I'm using bare versions of your models):

```
SELECT DISTINCT "movies"."id" FROM "movies" 
INNER JOIN "ratings" ON "ratings"."movie_id" = "movies"."id"
WHERE "ratings"."user_id" = ?  ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3

SELECT "movies"."id" AS t0_r0, "movies"."name" AS t0_r1, "movies"."created_at" AS t0_r2, 
"movies"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "ratings"."id" AS t1_r0, "ratings"."user_id" AS t1_r1, 
"ratings"."movie_id" AS t1_r2, "ratings"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "ratings"."updated_at" AS t1_r4 
FROM "movies" INNER JOIN "ratings" ON "ratings"."movie_id" = "movies"."id" 
WHERE "ratings"."user_id" = ? AND "movies"."id" IN (1) ORDER BY RANDOM() [["user_id", 1]]
```

Comment: That doesn't work - I'm still getting all the ratings for a particular movie, but I only want that user's rating for that particular movie

Comment: I'm really confused - although this should work, I'm only getting the fields of the Movies table and not the joined Ratings table

Comment: @user2635088, have you tried this query in the console, and confirmed that it isn't returning the fields? You might need to modify the `respond_with` args; I'm not really familiar with `Responder` and how it generates a JSON response. I just checked and the query is working appropriately for a small test; I'll post the generated SQL above.

Comment: Yes this is what it the query looks like in the console:
`SELECT "movies"."id" AS t0_r0, "movies"."name" AS t0_r1, "movies"."image" AS t0_r2, "ratings"."id" AS t1_r0, "ratings"."user_id" AS t1_r1, "ratings"."design_id" AS t1_r2, "ratings"."value" AS t1_r3, "ratings"."created_at" AS t1_r4, "ratings"."updated_at" AS t1_r5 FROM "movies" INNER JOIN "ratings" ON "ratings"."design_id" = "movies"."id" WHERE "movies"."id" = $1 AND "ratings"."user_id" = $2  [["id", 4], ["user_id", 1]]`



                                 And i've confirmed that a rating exists for user_id = 1 and movie_id = 4

Comment: When I do `movies.as_json(include: :ratings)`, it looks like it works fine. Maybe you just need to do `respond_with(movies, include: :ratings)` as you had at first? (Though like I said I don't know much about `respond_with`.)

Comment: If you create a second user who has rated the same movie, the then you run `respond_with(movies, include: :ratings)`, it gives the ratings of the second user as well. I just want the ratings of the first user

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate that, and it looks like your SQL wouldn't do that. Just for testing, could you try a) ensuring that you have copied the query in my `create` method exactly and b) replacing the `respond_with` command with `render json: movies.as_json(include: :ratings)`?